# phpmailer does not send email and does not display errors

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I use smtp gmail with phpmailer, i want to update my data and sent data using phpmailer. update data is success, but phpmailer not send that email and not display any error.  how i fix it?

this is my code

```
    date_default_timezone_get("Asia/Jakarta");
    $getdatasUser = $this->db->query("SELECT IDStatusPendidikan, IDPosisiJabatan FROM mspencaker WHERE IDUser='$iduser'")->result_array();
       $ab = $getdatasUser[0]['IDStatusPendidikan'];
       $ac = $getdatasUser[0]['IDPosisiJabatan'];
       $dateNow = date("Y-m-d");
       $lowonganhasil = $this->db->query("SELECT a.NamaLowongan, a.GajiPerbulan, a.IDLowongan, a.Penempatan, a.SyaratKhusus, b.NamaPerusahaan, b.IDPerusahaan, a.TglBerakhir FROM mslowongan as a JOIN msperusahaan as b ON b.IDPerusahaan = a.IDPerusahaan WHERE a.IDStatusPendidikan='$ab' AND a.IDPosisiJabatan='$ac' AND a.TglBerakhir >= '$dateNow' ORDER BY a.TglBerakhir DESC LIMIT 7")->result_array();
      // gambar
         if (file_exists(BASEPATH .'assets/file/temp/'.$idpencakertemp.'.jpg')){
             rename(realpath('assets/file/temp/'.$idpencakertemp.'.jpg'), realpath('assets/file/pencaker').'/'.$getmspencakerdata->IDPencaker.'.jpg');
            }
       // $this->load->model('EmailModel');
       $this->load->library('PHPMailer');
       $this->load->library('SMTP');

       $email_admin = 'example@gmail.com';
       $nama_admin = 'Nickname';
       $password_admin = 'mypassword';

       $mail = new PHPMailer();
       $mail->isSMTP();  
       $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
       $mail->Charset  = 'UTF-8';
       $mail->IsHTML(true);
       // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
       $mail->Port = 587;
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
       $mail->Username = $email_admin;
       $mail->Password = $password_admin;
       $mail->Mailer   = 'smtp';
       $mail->WordWrap = 100;       

       $mail->setFrom($email_admin);
       $mail->FromName = $nama_admin;
       $mail->addAddress($getmspencakerdata->Email);
       $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('assets/img-acc-pencaker.png', 'acc');
       $mail->Subject          = 'Akun Verifikasi '.$getmspencakerdata->NamaPencaker;
       $mail_data['subject']   = $getmspencakerdata->NamaPencaker;
       $mail_data['induk']     = $getmspencakerdata->NomorIndukPencaker;
       $mail_data['username']  = $getmsuserdata->Username;
       $mail_data['password']  = $getmsuserdata->Password;
       $mail_data['lowongan']  = $lowonganhasil;

       $message = $this->load->view('email_temp', $mail_data, TRUE);
       $mail->Body = $message;

       if ($mail->send()) {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('notifikasi', '<script>notifikasi("Pencaker Berhasil Ditambahkan", "success", "fa fa-check")</script>');
       } else {
           echo 'Message could not be sent.';
           echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       }
```

please help me to fix this code

Comment: I had similar issues when my hoster changed settings.  You need to display errors or add debugs to find out whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

```
// $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

If you disable debug output, it should not come as a surprise when you see no debug output. Uncomment this and set it to `3`, which is the right level for connection problems.

How do I know it's a connection problem? Because you're doing this:

```
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

This combination will not work. Either use port 587 and `'tls'`, or 465 and `'ssl'`; other combinations will not work.

These things are covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). Since you're using gmail, I recommend basing your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps).

Comment: thank you sir, this problem is fix after i read the troubleshooting guide